# GET CRASH LOG THROUGH INSTRUMENTS

Tags: javascript, instruments

I'm running some scripts in `UIAutomation`(Instrumnets /terminal). Assume on clicking on table cell in a `UITableView` the app crashes.

Currently the script is stopped since the app is crashed.
My question here is how to get crash log info through instrumnets using JavaScripts

Is there any possibility to export the logs and save in location automatically ?

P.S I understand that crash log can viewed manually in Xcode. We can also cross verify using time stamp.